# How to set environments variables while running a subprocess.call?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.8, csh

I am trying to run a command, which will be invoked in a different shell via subprocess.call(). Execution of this command expects certain env vars.
I have set these variables in a .csh file and trying to source it via subprocess.call(). But it's not working.
I also tried this
subprocess.call(command, shell = True, env = ".csh file path")
This also does not work. When I try to source it directly from CLI, it works fine.
Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Any environment variable you set in a subprocess is only set **for that subprocess itself**. As soon as the subprocess exits, the variables are gone. That's not unique to Python; that's how environment variables in UNIX work in _all_ languages.

Comment: That said, you can certainly have your command source your file and then run your executable, but you need to put that into the `command`; you can't use the environment argument for the purpose.

Comment: BTW, `shell=True` runs `/bin/sh`, not csh, by default, so unless the file you want to source is sh-compatible you'll need to set something like `executable='/bin/csh'` as an additional subprocess argument. (Mind, I'd argue that there hasn't been a good reason to use csh since the 1980s and that you'd be well-served to port your code to a modern, standard-compliant shell, but that's a larger discussion).

Answer (score 0):

`env` is a mapping of variable names to values to add to the environment, not the name of a file for the shell to source. For example, you could implement

```
FOOBAR=3 some_command
```

as

```
subprocess.call('some_command', shell=True, env={'FOOBAR': '3'})
```

If you need to source a file, you need to add that to the command you are running:

```
subprocess.call('source ".csh file path"; some_command', shell=True)
```

(As you mention `csh`, you need to explicitly tell `call` to use `csh` instead of the system shell.

```
subprocess.call('...', shell=True, executable='/bin/csh')
```

)